# Developing cache mechanism for Report retrieval module in Rest controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, caching

This is basically a design perspective question. I havent used any cache technique before. Let me tell you my project scenario first:

- In "Report" module I want to implement caching. Here depending on reportid and storeid, a SELECT query will be fired with reportid and storeid in WHERE clause.My RESTController will take "reportid" in input parameter and extract "storeid" from session call the DB from EJB. Query will return Report result in "String" format.Then in REST API I will process this string ;make it a text/pdf file ;attach this with "response" object using `response.setcontenttype("application/text")`
- How can I implement caching in this scenario? Is it possible to to cahche the entire text/pdf file?Or should i try to cache "String" result from query.
- Where should I store this cached content? In client machine/In browser /In back end server/ in any Java class itself using some static type ?

Please provide me an architectural view as well as implementation methods ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map data structures to implement caching.

Comment: Can you plz be more elaborate. i am new to this caching. i need a detailed explanation